# Not able to fetch the json response through angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Need to fetch the build values from apache.org. So i am using their api 
**https://builds.apache.org/api/json**

I tried angularjs $http.jsonp but not able to fetch the data.
In chrome console under network  json api is getting loaded but the data is not getting returned instead it is throwing the response as error.

```
app.controller("jsoncontroller",function($scope,$http){
   var url='https://builds.apache.org/api/json';
  $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data){
       console.log('success');
    })
    .error(function () {
      console.log('error')
    });
 });
```

Getting the error as

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 
error
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [jsonp angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#jsonp), you must append `JSON_CALLBACK` to the URL: `https://builds.apache.org/api/json?jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK`

However, that URL doesn't work because even when the callback parameter is specified, the server still sends back a content-type of application/json, instead of the expected application/javascript. This causes it to be parsed (evidently) by the json parser instead of the javascript callback needed for JSONP to work. I'm not versed enough in JSONP or Angular to know who is it fault here.

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsCGb/2/) with this working with another URL.

[Update]: The apache build server appears to use Jenkins, which has [disable JSONP](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/SECURITY/Jenkins+Security+Advisory+2013-02-16) from the remote API. You can verify this yourself by trying to hit their [jsonp endpoint](https://builds.apache.org/api/json?jsonp=callback), which returns a 403. You'll have to use another endpoint, no way I can see around this.

Comment: Yes agree, but i need to resolve the error and need to implement with //builds.apache.org/api/json

Comment: Any solutions you found?